# Add StackExchange.com to Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, data-explorer

With the vast amount of sites on the network, I was hoping to write some queries using the meta site data on the [Site listing](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page, such as 'Site traffic by age' or 'Question to answer ratio by site' to see which the most popular and fastest growing sites are, but the data isn't available to browse.

The data is certainly cached somewhere because of the crazy amount of calculations they take to work out, so could the table it's stored in be added to the list, or a special query page with the one table on it be added to the data explorer?

Comment: stackexchange.com is not a Q&A site just a portal, so it can't be added to Data Explorer. It does not have the vast majority of tables.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You could omit SE from the list but have the table show when you click on any other real site. Even if they couldn't, that's why I mentioned a special page with one table at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The data explorer is for Q&A sites.

StackExchange.com is not a Q&A site and though it is backed by a database (for certain functionality), there is nothing there that would make sense to put in the data explorer.

Comment: So you're saying if I want to work out the views per age for the sites I should just go `SUM`ing every value in every sites database one by one? Thanks, really appreciate it.